# “The announcement will come as (a) little surprise.” – Is using the indefinite article here a mistake?

Tags: articles

An exercise from Hewings’s “Advanced grammar in use”, Unit 52.

> Complete the sentences with
>
> - (a) few,
> - (a) little,
> - the few,
> - the little,
> - what few of what little,
>
> giving alternatives where possible.
>
> **The announcement will come as (_______________) surprise.**
>
> Answer: **little**

Is it incorrect to write:

“The announcement will come as **a** **little** surprise.”

After all, “surprise” is both countable and uncountable noun. What difference in meaning might there be between these two sentences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Little surprise" (determiner 2 below) means "not really a surprise", whereas "a little surprise" (adjective 1 below) might be a small gift or perhaps what a puppy did on the carpet.

> little
>
> adjective
>   1. small in size, amount, or degree (often used to convey an appealing diminutiveness or express an affectionate or condescending attitude). "the plants will grow into little bushes"
>
> determiner & pronoun
>   1. a small amount of. "we got a little help from a training scheme"
>   2. used to emphasize how small an amount is. "I have little doubt of their identity"

[Little](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/little)